# Different behavior when passing function reference or function name into _Widget.connect()

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a custom widget. The widget has a function that is connected to the click event of the DOM node. Later I want to connect a second function to the first one.

However this only works if I pass the function name instead of the function reference into the `connect` function in the first place.

This will work:

```
this.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', 'onClick' /*<-- Function name*/);
this.connect(this, 'onClick', 'onClick2');
```

This will not:

```
this.connect(this.domNode, 'onclick', this.onClick /*<-- Function reference*/);
this.connect(this, 'onClick', 'onClick2');
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c4pL1tvh/8/) is a fiddle demonstrating the behavior. When you click on the widget with the text 'Function name' two alerts will show, when you click on the widget with the text 'Function reference' only one alert will show.

Is this some kind of bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is the expected behavior. The reason why you are getting different results is because of how Dojo maintains "before" and "after". Let me first explain, the difference in the calls.

In the case `this.connect(this.domeNode, 'onclick', 'onClick');` you are passing a string parameter for the function. Internally it will call something like `this['onClick']()`, here the function is the same which is in the widget (scope is also maintained, which is the widget).

In the second case, you are passing the function parameter as a instance of the function ( you may as well create a `var functionParam = this.onClick` and pass it as parameter, it will be the same ), since it is already a function, dojo will execute is something like `functionParameter()`(here aslo the scope will be the widget). Since the scope & function is the same for both case there is no difference in how the function is executed or the result of the output.

Moving to the interesting part, When you setup another function to be called after the execution of the original function. Dojo has to maintain this information somewhere, so it replaces your original function with a object/function which contains all the information like `after, before and original function`. And it has a mechanism to execute them in the order.

So to answer your question, The first case, the dojo internally will execute the method it has replaced your function with, thus will also call the second function. In the second case, the instance of the method you passed will be called and not the function of the widget(`widget.onClick`), so the second function will not be called.

Also avoid using `connect`, it is a deprecated method and internally will use `dojo/on` and `dojo/aspect`. You may as well use them and reduce the over head cost of Dojo doing it for you.

> Deprecated, will be removed in 2.0, use this.own(on(...)) or
>   this.own(aspect.after(...)) instead.

Comment: So you mean when I connect `onClick2` to `onClick`, dojo replaces `onClick` with a dynamically created function and in the second case it does not replace `myWidget.onClick` but rather only `functionParameter`?

Comment: I am using `connect` because this is legacy code still using the pre 1.7 syntax.

Comment: No in both the cases the `myWidget.onClick` is replaced. But, only in the first case `myWidget.onClick` is called, whereas for second case `functionParameter` is called, which is the instance of your original 'onClick'.

Comment: Thanks. I still think this difference should be mentioned in the documenation. I am pretty sure I did not read about it.